# Beginning ASP.NET MVC with VB.net 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, model-view-controller, .net-3.5

Where can I find a good tutorial on learning ASP.NET MVC using VB.net 2008 as the language? Most in-depth tutorials that I found in searching the web were written in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding the word "VB" to your searches??

http://www.myvbprof.com/2007_Version/MVC_Intro_Tutorial.aspx

http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-07-vb.aspx

<[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170119043903/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/jwhitehorn/archive/2007/12/10/117569.aspx)>

Answer (score 0):

http://quickstarts.asp.net/3-5-extensions/mvc/default.aspx

Is that relevant?