# whats the best asp.net mvc tutorial(s) out there? <EOM>

Tags: asp.net-mvc

answer could include blogs, podcast, etc

Comment: There 's a step by step complete tutorial at [code zone4](http://codezone4.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/building-asp-net-mvc3-applications/). I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 5):

See:

http://asp.net/mvc

[ASP.NET MVC quick start - a one-stop tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668/asp-net-mvc-quick-start-a-one-stop-tutorial)

[Beginning ASP.NET MVC with VB.net 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642/beginning-asp-net-mvc-with-vb-net-2008)

Answer (score 3):

Free [first 185 pages](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx) of [image: Hanselbook].

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the sample project [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) by Microsoft dev's - Phil Haack, Hanselman and ScottGu.

[Here's the free](http://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf) CC licensed Ebook

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the storefront sample app made by Rob Connery. You can follow the screencast on his blog and download the source code from CodePlex.  On his blog you can follow a series of screencast and watch Rob building from the ground  a real world online shopping site.  He explores real world issues with respect to MVC – and tries to stick to best practices.  I found the code and the screencast to be an extraordinary source of inspiration (not only for MVC).

http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/

Comment: Link is not available any more.