# .NET MVC learning

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am a UI Designer. My key areas of expertise are in XHTML, CSS and Javascript. I don't have any experience in Server Side Programming.

I've joined a new company as a UI Developer where I need to learn .NET MVC using C#. I don't know anything about ASP, C#, MVC etc. To learn these, where should I start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good introduction to asp.net MVC is the [1st chapter of Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html). There are links part way down the page to the [1st chapter download](http://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf), [the completed code](http://www.codeplex.com/nerddinner) and somewhere to [discuss it](http://p2p.wrox.com/book-professional-asp-net-mvc-1-0-isbn-978-0-470-38461-9-490/).

There's also the [asp.net/mvc site](http://www.asp.net/mvc), and pretty much anything [tagged "mvc" on Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/tags/MVC/default.aspx). Scott Guthrie is the guy that runs the development teams that own ASP.NET, IIS and the CLR (and more!), which pretty much covers everything that makes up MVC. Some of the content there is a bit beyond "beginner" but it'll certainly help you to read around the subject. For example he has two sets of links from the middle of last year ([May 30th](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/05/30/may-30th-links-asp-net-ajax-asp-net-mvc-visual-studio.aspx) and [June 7th](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/06/07/june-7th-links-asp-net-ajax-asp-net-mvc-visual-studio.aspx)) from which I've extracted the following resources that are probably of specific interest to someone who's primarily a UI developer:

- [Query Auto-Complete Text Box with ASP.NET MVC](http://flux88.com/blog/jquery-auto-complete-text-box-with-asp-net-mvc/)
- [Using the jQuery Grid with ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx)
- [More ASP.NET MVC Best Practices](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/06/More-ASPNET-MVC-Best-Practices.aspx) (not specifically UI, but certainly useful to know!)

A very high level introduction to C# is contained in [.NET Book Zero](http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/DotNetBookZero11.pdf) (**PDF**) by Charles Petzold, it's subtitled "What the C or C++ Programmer Needs to Know about C# and the .NET Framework", but as a broad overview of C# and the CLR, it's not a bad place to start.

Answer (score 2):

You should start with the official asp.net MVC page @

http://www.asp.net/mvc

and have a look at the examples. Than skip to the NerdDinner tutorial to get some global insight in the framework and such:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx

That nerddinner might be in MVC1 but I did see an adaption to MVC2 somewhere.

**edit**

If you have never programmed I suggest you buy a book as well. Do a lookup here on SO and skim for the most mentioned books and select a top 3 book. Although im not sure if you should buy a general "how to program" book as well.

Have fun :)

Comment: well,you mean framework, not language?

Comment: thnx...i started with asp.net/mvc but since i dont have knowledge in c#, i got stuck somewhere. my question is which one should I learn first ? c# or ASP or ....

Comment: Aneesh - it'd almost certainly be easier for you to learn c# first as you can start with *just* that, then add in asp.net and MVC to the mix. Take a look at the link to ".NET Book Zero" in my answer =)

Answer (score 0):

MSDN is a very good place to start: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/52f3sw5c%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you should start with :

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp

http://asp.net/mvc

[ASP.NET MVC quick start - a one-stop tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668/asp-net-mvc-quick-start-a-one-stop-tutorial)

[Beginning ASP.NET MVC with VB.net 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642/beginning-asp-net-mvc-with-vb-net-2008)

Answer (score 0):

The [NerdDinner Tutorial on Amazon](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) seems to be pretty good.

Generally, I prefer to post the code rather than a link only, but that's a big tutorial to post as an answer.